# Update a shell script change in all directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

i have created a shell script in 10 directories.

```
a/we.sh
b/we.sh
c/we.sh
.
.
.
.
```

how to update a change in the shell script in all the directories in unix/Linux.

Comment: As @rakib hinted, don't do it. You're much better off using symlinks or (in the standard Unix way) using the directory as a parameter to the script. It shouldn't matter which directory a script is in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
find . -iname 'we.sh' -type f -exec cp '/path/to/modified/script/we.sh {} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the symbolic link feature. Use the `ln` command with all the files you've created. In this way you'll change one file and will show up at every linked path. To create a symbolic link you can use this simple command - `ln -s script.sh sample.sh` here `sample.sh` is the path which will be created.